# How can I manually set the CPU frequency?

Tags: shell, cpu, root, cpu-speed

I have tried the following from shell:

```
cat scaling_governor
userspace

cat scaling_available_frequencies
3326000 3325000 3192000 3059000 2926000 2793000 2660000 2527000 2394000 2261000 2128000   1995000 1862000 1729000 1596000 

echo 2793000 > scaling_setspeed
bash: scaling_setspeed: Permission denied

sudo echo 2793000 > scaling_setspeed
bash: scaling_setspeed: Permission denied

echo 2793000 | sudo tee scaling_setspeed
bash: scaling_setspeed: Permission denied
```

I am not able to understand why this is occuring. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [man cpufreq-set](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cpufreq-set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some processors/architectures doesn't allow this.

If it's allowed, kernel must be properly configured and/or appropriate modules must be loaded.

Take a look at this...

http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/How_to_make_use_of_Dynamic_Frequency_Scaling

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Try

`sudo sh -c "echo 2793000 > /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_setspeed"`

Not sure why your third attempt doesn't work, but maybe this one will do?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This looks like a legit answer. Did you try it yourself? or have you edited this file yourself in the past?

Comment: As for my personal case, I did it exactly this way. Working on a Nehalem i5 Dell Latitude E6410 with Kubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the scaling_governor first to "userspace" else scaling_setspeed will not accept any value AND you have to be a root user.